# Android GoogleSignInAccount holds no profile information i.e all get methods return null

Tags: java, android, google-api

I am trying to implement a simple login button with Google.
I set my sign in options like this :

```
googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .build();

googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
            .build();
```

On the click listener of my button :

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
});
```

When I login, my resultcode is RESULT_OK so I go through the `if` statement without any problems.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            GoogleSignInResult res = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

            GoogleSignInAccount account = res.getSignInAccount();
            info.setText(account.getDisplayName());
        }else{
            info.setText("failed");
        }
    }else{

    }
}
```

The problem is with this `GoogleSignInAccount` object:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = res.getSignInAccount();
```

Every method called on this object returns `null`. I made this to demonstrate:
[image: Null results]

Edit: `res.isSuccess()` returns `true`

Comment: Can you check if res.isSuccess() is true before getting account information?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention res.isSuccess() does return true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GoogleSignInAccount returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506840/googlesigninaccount-returns-null)

Comment: even i am having same issue ? did you solved it ?